# How to compare position of an element with prior elements after a test condition in a for-each loop with XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I loop over some elements (Generation), and then test if their Index match with other nodes to determine what type of element it is. I want to display a title related to the type of the element if it exists but only once.

Here's an example of my problem :

XML :

```
<element_collection>    
   <element>
      <index>1</index>
   </element>
   <element>
      <index>2</index>
   </element>
   <element>
      <index>3</index>
   </element>
   <element>
      <index>4</index>
   </element>
</element_collection>

<element_link_type_1_collection>
   <element_link_type_1>
      <element_index>2</element_index>
   </element_link_type_1>
   <element_link_type_1>
      <element_index>3</element_index>
   </element_link_type_1>
   <element_link_type_1>
      <element_index>4</element_index>
   </element_link_type_1>
</element_link_type_1_collection>

<element_link_type_2_collection>
   <element_link_type_2>
      <element_index>1</element_index>
   </element_link_type_2>
<element_link_type_1>
      <element_index>4</element_index>
   </element_link_type_1>
</element_link_type_2_collection>
```

XSL for-each loop :

```
<xsl:for-each select="element_collection/element">
    <xsl:variable name="id_element" select="Index"/>
    
    <xsl:choose>
    <!-- condition for type 1 only -->
        <xsl:when test="element_link_type_1_collection/element_link_type_1/element_index = $id_element 
    and not(element_link_type_2_collection/element_link_type_2/element_index = $id_element)">

    <!-- treatment -->
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

You see with this loop I look for all elements and check if their Index is present in the `element_link_type` collections, if they are present only in the `collection_type_1` the elements are of `type 1`, if they are present in both `type_1` and `type_2` they are of both types.

My problem is that I want to display a title for the category of the element but only if the elements of the type exists. In my example I would like to return something like this :

> Type 1 : indexes - 2,3
>
> Type 2 : indexes - 1
>
> Type 1 and 2 : indexes - 4

In order to do that I wanted to find the position of the first element to match my condition, but I can't seem to find a way to do that.

Comment: Is there a typo in your XML? There is an `element_link_type_1` under the `element_link_type_2_collection` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it might be easy to define some keys to look up the collection items

```
<xsl:key name="type1" match="element_link_type_1" use="element_index" />
<xsl:key name="type2" match="element_link_type_2" use="element_index" />
```

One way to solve your problem though, is that rather than just iterating over the elements once, and working out their type, try selecting the relevant items for each type separately. For example, to get "Type 1" elements, do this...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="element_collection/element[key('type1', index) and not(key('type2', index))]" />
```

This does have the slight disadvantage that you would check each element three times though:

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:key name="type1" match="element_link_type_1" use="element_index" />
  <xsl:key name="type2" match="element_link_type_2" use="element_index" />

  <xsl:template match="elements">
      <xsl:text>Type 1: </xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="element_collection/element[key('type1', index) and not(key('type2', index))]" />
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

      <xsl:text>Type 2: </xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="element_collection/element[key('type2', index) and not(key('type1', index))]" />
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

      <xsl:text>Type 1 and 2: </xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="element_collection/element[key('type1', index) and key('type2', index)]" />
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="element">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="index" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me in so that I needed to use keys and since i'm fairly new to xslt I didn't know. The rest of the answer is not really applicable to my case but it might be useful, thanks a lot again.